# Run nodejs in nginx server (one file project)

Tags: php, node.js, nginx

hi i got a problem running nodejs in my php project, im planning run my apps in nginx, nodejs, php-fpm, and pm2

but i tryna access the test file its doesn't work and the nginx error log is like this

`2022/03/10 21:04:04 [error] 14875#14875: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ips, server: domainname, request: "GET /test.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:7000/test.js", host: "domainname`

and this is my nginx configuration file

```
#Names a server and declares the listening port
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domainname;

    #Configures the publicly served root directory
    #Configures the index file to be served
    root /var/www/domainname;
    index index.html index.htm;

    #These lines create a bypass for certain pathnames
    #www.example.com/test.js is now routed to port 3000
    #instead of port 80
    location ~* \.(js)$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

i already install nodejs but the .js file is not work, after the js work ill try to add some conf for nginx php

```
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
```

but the problem right now is the .js file is not work how to solve that problem ? i already allow firewall at 7000/tcp but its not working

Comment: Does something listening on port 7000? BTW: Why do you pass all *.js requests to `http://localhost:7000`? JavaScript/node.js is not the same as php, where you "forward" all requests made to a php file to the interpreter.

Comment: well i try to make nodejs running and the .js is running too, i just figure it out

Comment: the extention .js is return 404 not found idk whats wrong already running the node server.js https://prnt.sc/_PcRgyfRenDg

Comment: @Marc what should i do ? i forgot my last configuration and my server got deleted im confused

Comment: You are mixing server side javascript (node.js) and client side javascript. Refactor your nginx config: Define a path for your node.js application (e.g. "/api", full path: `http://example.com/api` and forward all requests that are made to "/api" to your node.js app that listents on port 7000. keyword: nginx reverse proxy". And handle all files that end with *.js as client side js and serve this files just as regular static files. (Another approch to the /api path would to work with (sub)-domains) e.g. node.example.com There are more than one possible solution.